# Problem running PHPUnit

Tags: 12.04, php

I seem to be having a problem with PHPUnit running properly on my machine.

I have Pear installed and running correctly on my machine, and then followed this guide to the letter:

http://www.giocc.com/installing-phpunit-on-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal.html

But when I type `phpunit` in terminal in Ubuntu, I get the following response:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(File/Iterator/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/thalley887/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 45
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/thalley887/pear/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. require() /home/thalley887/pear/bin/phpunit:43
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'File/Iterator/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/thalley887/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 45
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/thalley887/pear/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. require() /home/thalley887/pear/bin/phpunit:43
```

I have checked in my php.ini file and have the following line:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php"
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. Please comment if I can give anymore details. If I can't fix this I am going to jump out of the window!!

Answer (score 0):

Launch a 
`sudo find /usr/share/ -name Iterator  -type d | grep File/Iterator`

If you have no results, the packages is missing, reinstall with

`pear install phpunit/File_Iterator`

If still does not work, try reinstall phpunit

`pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/phpunit`